# defining static arrays in Java

Tags: java

hello I have some question about writing class in Java, why this one is not working:

```
public class EvenFibonacciSequences {

    static final int num = 45;

    static int calculated[num];
...
}
```

how can I write it correctly?
thanks in advance

Comment: If you are trying to calculate the even Fibonacci values, you don't need to define an array. You just need one loop which can calculate one even value per iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want

```
static int[] calculated = new int[num];
```

At least, I think that's right (have not dealt with Java in a while.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare an array with an array size.It is illegal. Instead, you should do it (specifying the array size) during array initialization as @likeIT has given.